# Textbox - background color appears only on click

Tags: html, css

I have a textbox in HTML. I changed it's background color to gray but when I run it the background color appears only after I click the textbox.

```css
.txtUsername {
  position: absolute;
  left: 67%;
  top: 30%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 177px;
  background: rgb(34,34,34);
  color: white; 
  border: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<input class="txtUsername" name="username" type="text">
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/bp3sg5nd/) - do you have any `:focus` styling for `.txtUsername` or any `input` elements elsewhere in your stylesheet?

Comment: @ScottKaye: no i didn't

Comment: Well there has to be something else on your page overriding the style, as you can see in my example, the code you provided works fine.

Comment: post your entire stylesheet please

Comment: @Electricspider Scott is correct. You need to add more to the question for us to be able to replicate it. As it stands, the code you provided works so we will need more information. One debugging tool is to right click the element and click "inspect" then on the right hand side you should see the CSS that is effecting that element and what file/line that CSS is coming from.

Comment: Did you try on all browser ? or only one ?